# Does Borland C++Builder 6 have a debug-logging facility?

Tags: c++builder, c++builder-6

I am using Borland C++Builder 6.0 (don't ask). Is there any debug-logging mechanism in this IDE? I'm looking for something analogous to writing to `stderr` from console C/C++ applications, or calling `NSLog` from a Cocoa application.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Win32 API [`OutputDebugString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) function to send messages to the IDE's Event Log messages window while the app is running inside the debugger.  This function is also useful even if your app is not running inside the IDE debugger, because third-party loggers, like [SysInternals DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647), can catch and display the same messages.

Comment: How do I open the Messages window? I don't see it anywhere.

Comment: View > Debug Windows > Event Log